# Creating an entity code first database with complex objects with relationships between them

Tags: c#, entity-framework, nested, code-first, relationship

I'm trying to create a database with code first entity framework and am not clear on how this is done with complex nested objects. I've read the tutorials on MS and some blogs etc but they seem very simplistic and am hoping someone can give me some pointers on how to do this correctly.

I have an app communicating with a web server. Each device enrolls in the server, and from time to time some data is pushed/pulled from the server to the client. Right now I am creating some surveys.
Each device can have some survey questions that they were asked. Each survey has a list of answers that they were given. Each answer should be paired with the question it belongs to as well as the device that gave that answer.

so here is some partial code. Please advice the correct way to create the relationship that I need as well as the structure of the classes in the best recommended practice.

```
public class Device
    {
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public virtual string Udid { set; get; }
        public virtual string Contact { set; get; }
        public virtual DateTime EnrollDate { get; set; }
        public virtual List<SurveyQuestion> Surveys { get; set; } 
    }

public class SurveyQuestion
    {
        public virtual int Id { set; get; }
        public virtual string Question { get; set; }
        public virtual List<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
        public virtual DateTime Time { get; set; }
    }

public class Answer
    {
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual string UserAnswer { get; set; }
        public virtual DateTime Time { get; set; }
        public virtual SurveyQuestion SurveyQuestion { get; set; }
        public virtual Device DeviceWhichAnswered {get; set;}
    }
```

Abstraction of datasource

```
public interface IDataSource
    {
        IQueryable<Device> Devices { get; }
        IQueryable<SurveyQuestion> SurveyQuestions { get; }
        IQueryable<Answer> Answers { get; }
        void Save();
    }
```

and the concrete class that implements the entity db

```
public class MyDb : DbContext, IDataSource
    {
        public MyDb() : base("DefaultConnection")
        {
            Debug.Write(Database.Connection.ConnectionString);
        }
        public DbSet<Device> Devices { get; set; }
        public DbSet<SurveyQuestion> SurveyQuestions { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
        IQueryable<Device> IDataSource.Devices
        {
            get { return Devices; }
        }
        IQueryable<SurveyQuestion> IDataSource.SurveyQuestions
        {
            get { return SurveyQuestions; }
        }
        IQueryable<Answer> IDataSource.Answers
        {
            get { return Answers; }
        }
}
```

Comment: shouldnt SurveyQuestion contain a List<Answer> instead of List<string>? Anyway, what's the problem you run into? The question is a bit unclear

Comment: Did you test it? It looks OK - except the `List<string>` property which can't be mapped to the DB. It should be `List<Answer>`, I guess.

Comment: There are several practices (fluent vs attribute etc) but none is an obvious 'best'. You'll have to be more specific.

Comment: I don't think your `IQueryable<T>` properties serve a clear purpose.

Comment: sorry about the typo, that should be list<answers>. I've seen code that instead of having nested class of survey holding answers , had some "strange" relationship of survey with an int of answer_id , and then some relationship answer pointing back to survey_id (hope that is clear). Is this necessary or can I disregard the relationship of answer to question, and only have a nested answer in each survey_question.

Comment: about the iqueryable , I am not sure if it is necessary but I've seen in a few times. I think DBset is queryable anyway isn't it?

Comment: You do not have 'nested' classes but associations that will map onto FK relations. Putting the Ids in yourself is optional. EF will add them otherwise.